# In Android, is there any way to implement fast scrolling in the new RecyclerView?

Tags: android, listview

I've converted all of the large `ListView` components in my app into the new `RecyclerView` using the support library v7. And they do work much better/faster/smoother. But I can't find any way to enable fast scrolling (like the `setFastScrollEnabled()` method in ListView). Is there any way to get that working?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the answer i gave for the following post. I dont know will it help you much but it just my first version.

[Android L: Fast scroll for the RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450683/android-l-fast-scroll-for-the-recyclerview/28083631#28083631)

i used recyclerView.scrollToPosition(psoition); rather then recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position); because the reyclerview basically scroll through the entire list to go to the position and this takes time if you have a long list.

Answer (score -1):

No, currently there isn't any way. `RecyclerView` doesn't implement the fast scroll as the `ListView`, so the only way to do this is implemented it yourself.

Comment: The question was if it's possible to implement it. Your answer  of "do it yourself" is useless