# Android L: Fast scroll for the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, fastscroll

I'm trying to use `RecyclerView` in my application with lots of data in it and would like to make a fast scroll for it, just like for the `ListView`. Approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17341632/1889928) worked for me with `ListView`, but does not work for the `RecyclerView`. Even if I set fast scroll to `true` in `RecyclerView` layout, it still does not work:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true" />
```

Does the `RecyclerView` supports the fast scroll in Android L? Can't find anything about this in documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing you will find in RecyclerView is the basic implementation of the recycling logic. It is the complete polar opposite of ListView in that it offers you maximum customisability (you can achieve any unique layout you want unlike ListView), but it has almost nothing built in with it (unlike ListView which has numerous features like the fast scroll thumb).

If you want to add something like the fast scroll feature, you're going to need to develop it on your own for now.

> New **fastScrollEnabled** boolean flag for RecyclerView. If enabled, fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable, fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable, fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable, and fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable must be set. Now available on [Support Library 26.0.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0)

Comment: Any news about it? RecyclerView is already an official support library view... Has anyone succeeded adding a fast scroller for it?

Comment: I am interested in the same feature. Has someone found a solution for the fast scrolling or maybe there is an example somewhere that can be pointed out..?

Answer (score 3):

i have made one for myself using https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView/tree/master/src/com/woozzu/android/widget

and changing the ListView to RecylerView

```
public class IndexableRecylerView extends RecyclerView implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

    public IndexScroller mScroller = null;

    public IndexableRecylerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
 init();
    }

    public IndexableRecylerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
 init();
    }

    public IndexableRecylerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
 init();
    }

public void init() {
    addOnItemTouchListener(this);
}


    public void setFastScrollEnabled(boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            if (mScroller == null)
                mScroller = new IndexScroller(getContext(), this);
        } else {
            if (mScroller != null) {
                mScroller.hide();
                mScroller = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);

        // Overlay index bar
        if (mScroller != null)
            mScroller.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (mScroller != null)
          mScroller.show();

        // Intercept ListView's touch event
        if (mScroller != null && mScroller.onTouchEvent(ev))
            return true;


        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public void setIndexAdapter(List<String> sectionName, List<Integer> sectionPosition) {
        if (mScroller != null)
            mScroller.notifyChanges(sectionName, sectionPosition);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if (mScroller != null)
            mScroller.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    public void stopScroll()
    {
        try
        {
            super.stopScroll();
        }
        catch( NullPointerException exception )
        {
            Log.i("RecyclerView", "NPE caught in stopScroll");
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    if (mScroller != null && mScroller.contains(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
        mScroller.show();
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
}

}
```

This class draws the indexers at the side and allow you to scroll on them and scroll the recylerview too..

```
public class IndexScroller {

    private float mIndexbarWidth;
    private float mIndexbarMargin;
    private float mPreviewPadding;
    private float mDensity;
    private float mScaledDensity;
    private float mAlphaRate;
    private int mState = STATE_HIDDEN;
    private int mListViewWidth;
    private int mListViewHeight;
    private int mCurrentSection = -1;
    private boolean mIsIndexing = false;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView = null;
    public List<String> mSections = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Integer> mSectionPosition = new ArrayList<>();
    private RectF mIndexbarRect;

    private static final int STATE_HIDDEN = 0;
    private static final int STATE_SHOWING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_SHOWN = 2;
    private static final int STATE_HIDING = 3;

    public IndexScroller(Context context, RecyclerView lv) {
        mDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        mScaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
        recyclerView = lv;

        mIndexbarWidth = 20 * mDensity;
        mIndexbarMargin = 10 * mDensity;
        mPreviewPadding = 5 * mDensity;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mState == STATE_HIDDEN)
            return;

        // mAlphaRate determines the rate of opacity
        Paint indexbarPaint = new Paint();
        indexbarPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        indexbarPaint.setAlpha((int) (64 * mAlphaRate));
        indexbarPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mIndexbarRect, 5 * mDensity, 5 * mDensity, indexbarPaint);

        if (mSections != null && mSections.size() > 0) {
            // Preview is shown when mCurrentSection is set
            if (mCurrentSection >= 0) {
                Paint previewPaint = new Paint();
                previewPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                previewPaint.setAlpha(96);
                previewPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                previewPaint.setShadowLayer(3, 0, 0, Color.argb(64, 0, 0, 0));

                Paint previewTextPaint = new Paint();
                previewTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                previewTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                previewTextPaint.setTextSize(50 * mScaledDensity);

                float previewTextWidth = previewTextPaint.measureText(mSections.get(mCurrentSection));
                float previewSize = 2 * mPreviewPadding + previewTextPaint.descent() - previewTextPaint.ascent();
                RectF previewRect = new RectF((mListViewWidth - previewSize) / 2
                        , (mListViewHeight - previewSize) / 2
                        , (mListViewWidth - previewSize) / 2 + previewSize
                        , (mListViewHeight - previewSize) / 2 + previewSize);

                canvas.drawRoundRect(previewRect, 5 * mDensity, 5 * mDensity, previewPaint);
                canvas.drawText(mSections.get(mCurrentSection), previewRect.left + (previewSize - previewTextWidth) / 2 - 1
                        , previewRect.top + mPreviewPadding - previewTextPaint.ascent() + 1, previewTextPaint);
            }

            Paint indexPaint = new Paint();
            indexPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            indexPaint.setAlpha((int) (255 * mAlphaRate));
            indexPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            indexPaint.setTextSize(12 * mScaledDensity);

            float sectionHeight = (mIndexbarRect.height() - 2 * mIndexbarMargin) / mSections.size();
            float paddingTop = (sectionHeight - (indexPaint.descent() - indexPaint.ascent())) / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < mSections.size(); i++) {
                float paddingLeft = (mIndexbarWidth - indexPaint.measureText(mSections.get(i))) / 2;
                canvas.drawText(mSections.get(i), mIndexbarRect.left + paddingLeft
                        , mIndexbarRect.top + mIndexbarMargin + sectionHeight * i + paddingTop - indexPaint.ascent(), indexPaint);
            }
        }
    }


    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                // If down event occurs inside index bar region, start indexing
                if (mState != STATE_HIDDEN && contains(ev.getX(), ev.getY())) {
                    setState(STATE_SHOWN);

                    // It demonstrates that the motion event started from index bar
                    mIsIndexing = true;
                    // Determine which section the point is in, and move the list to that section
                    mCurrentSection = getSectionByPoint(ev.getY());
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mSectionPosition.get(mCurrentSection));
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mIsIndexing) {
                    // If this event moves inside index bar
                    if (contains(ev.getX(), ev.getY())) {
                        // Determine which section the point is in, and move the list to that section
                        mCurrentSection = getSectionByPoint(ev.getY());
                        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(mSectionPosition.get(mCurrentSection));
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (mIsIndexing) {
                    mIsIndexing = false;
                    mCurrentSection = -1;
                }
                if (mState == STATE_SHOWN) {
                    setState(STATE_HIDING);
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mListViewWidth = w;
        mListViewHeight = h;
        mIndexbarRect = new RectF(w - mIndexbarMargin - mIndexbarWidth
                , mIndexbarMargin
                , w - mIndexbarMargin
                , h - mIndexbarMargin);
    }

    public void show() {
        if (mState == STATE_HIDDEN)
            setState(STATE_SHOWING);
        else if (mState == STATE_HIDING)
            setState(STATE_HIDING);
    }

    public void hide() {
        if (mState == STATE_SHOWN)
            setState(STATE_HIDING);
    }

    private void setState(int state) {
        if (state < STATE_HIDDEN || state > STATE_HIDING)
            return;

        mState = state;
        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_HIDDEN:
                // Cancel any fade effect
                mHandler.removeMessages(0);
                break;
            case STATE_SHOWING:
                // Start to fade in
                mAlphaRate = 0;
                fade(0);
                break;
            case STATE_SHOWN:
                // Cancel any fade effect
                mHandler.removeMessages(0);
                break;
            case STATE_HIDING:
                // Start to fade out after three seconds
                mAlphaRate = 1;
                fade(3000);
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(float x, float y) {
        // Determine if the point is in index bar region, which includes the right margin of the bar
        return (x >= mIndexbarRect.left && y >= mIndexbarRect.top && y <= mIndexbarRect.top + mIndexbarRect.height());
    }

    private int getSectionByPoint(float y) {
        if (mSections == null || mSections.size() == 0)
            return 0;
        if (y < mIndexbarRect.top + mIndexbarMargin)
            return 0;
        if (y >= mIndexbarRect.top + mIndexbarRect.height() - mIndexbarMargin)
            return mSections.size() - 1;
        return (int) ((y - mIndexbarRect.top - mIndexbarMargin) / ((mIndexbarRect.height() - 2 * mIndexbarMargin) / mSections.size()));
    }

    private void fade(long delay) {
        mHandler.removeMessages(0);
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageAtTime(0, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + delay);
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            switch (mState) {
                case STATE_SHOWING:
                    // Fade in effect
                    mAlphaRate += (1 - mAlphaRate) * 0.2;
                    if (mAlphaRate > 0.9) {
                        mAlphaRate = 1;
                        setState(STATE_SHOWN);
                    }

                    recyclerView.invalidate();
                    fade(10);
                    break;
                case STATE_SHOWN:
                    // If no action, hide automatically
                    setState(STATE_HIDING);
                    break;
                case STATE_HIDING:
                    // Fade out effect
                    mAlphaRate -= mAlphaRate * 0.2;
                    if (mAlphaRate < 0.1) {
                        mAlphaRate = 0;
                        setState(STATE_HIDDEN);
                    }

                    recyclerView.invalidate();
                    fade(10);
                    break;
            }
        }

    };


    public void notifyChanges(List<String> sectionName, List<Integer> sectionPosition) {

// Pre-calculate and pass your section header and position

        mSections = sectionNames;
        mSectionPosition = sectionPosition;

    }}
```

This is only a fast fix i modified to test it. Seems to work for me, with a list of 3100 items. When you set the Items to your adapter, you need to calculate your section header and the position. In my case i iterate through my pre-sorted list and take the position of the first item for each character and put into a list and pass to the public void notifyChanges(List sectionName, List sectionPosition). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Can you try to refine it more? I'd really like to have it in my application

Comment: @Aky maybe this might help you https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller

Comment: Don't worry I made my own custom scroller, hopefully will release a library of it

Answer (score 2):

One more good solution which I've found is described in a good [article by Mark Allison](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/recyclerview-fastscroll-part-2/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=fcea034f71-Android_Weekly_145&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-fcea034f71-337837633) about how to implement your own custom fast scroll for `RecyclerView`. Worth to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [**library here**](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller) ("RecyclerViewFastScroller") , which might be of some help.

Someone published it from a similar post I've written, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27798212/878126)

Answer (score 1):

I have made a [library](https://github.com/FutureMind/recycler-fast-scroll) to cope with this problem. There are quite a lot of customisation options now.